# Disable singleton when testing with ScalaTest in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, scalatest

I have the following `@Singleton` in my Play for Scala application that loads on startup:

```
@Singleton
class Scheduler @Inject()(@Named("mainEtl") mainEtl: ActorRef, system: ActorSystem) {

// some code  
}
```

This is the module where Scheduler is declared. The module is enabled in `application.conf`:

```
class Module extends AbstractModule {
  def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[Scheduler]).asEagerSingleton
  }
}
```

And the related module definition to configure the `@Named` injected object, also declared in `application.conf`:

```
class AkkaBindings extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
   def configure = {
     bindActor[MainEtl]("mainEtl")
  }
}
```

When I run any ScalaTest test, apparently the singleton starts running because I get an error saying that it doesn't find `MainEtl` (the object injected in the `Scheduler` class). The point is that I **don't** need to run the singleton for my tests, so I need to disable it.

This is how I invoke the Play application in my tests:

```
class ManageBanksTest extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite with MockitoSugar {

  implicit override lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().build

   // more test code  
}
```

This is how I tried to disable it, but it doesn't work as I get the same error:

```
  implicit override lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .disable[Scheduler]
    .build
```

Alternatively, I could mock `Scheduler`, but I would have to mock also the `@Named` injected object and I couldn't find information on how to achieve that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your test class that you have written till now?

Comment: Added the test class, note that the @Singleton is not invoked in the test, Play is running it behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution: to disable the Module class not to declare Scheduler as singleton:

```
implicit override lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .disable[Module]
    .build
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
   import com.google.inject.name.Names 
   import org.specs2.mock.Mockito
   import play.api.inject.guice.{GuiceApplicationBuilder, GuiceableModule} 

   val modules = Option(new AbstractModule {
       override def configure() = {
         val mockMainETL = mock[MainEtl]
         bind(classOf[ActorRef])
         .annotatedWith(Names.named("mainEtl"))
         .toInstance(mockMainETL)


       val mock1 = mock[ManageBanksDAO]
       mock1.readMany answers { _ => Future{seqMany}}
       val mockManageBanks = mock[ManageBanks]
       bind(classOf[ManageBanks]).toInstance(new ManageBanks(mock1))
       }
    })
    lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .overrides(modules.map(GuiceableModule.guiceable).toSeq: _*)
    .build
```

Try configuring your mock inside modules and add those modules while initializing your application. This will inject custom mocks.

Also instead of this :

```
val controller = new ManageBanks(mock1)
```

Try this:

```
 val controller = app.injector.instanceOf(classOf[ManageBanks])
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `recursive value mockMainETL needs type` in the `configure()` method, so I added the type: `val mockMainETL: MainEtl = mock[MainEtl]` but I get this error in `.toInstance(mockMainETL)`: `type mismatch; found : tasks.etl.MainEtl required: akka.actor.ActorRef Note: implicit value app is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type`

Comment: val mockMainETL: ActorRef = mock[MainEtl]   try this.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `type mismatch; found : tasks.etl.MainEtl required: akka.actor.ActorRef Note: implicit value app is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type`

Comment: remove implicit from your app

Comment: I'm still getting `type mismatch; found : tasks.etl.MainEtl required: akka.actor.ActorRef` in line ` val mockMainETL: ActorRef = mock[MainEtl]`

Comment: MainEtl extends Actor, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142191/discussion-between-sumeet-sharma-and-ps0604).

Comment: this is not working, If I define Actor or ActorRef in `val mockMainETL: ActorRef = mock[MainEtl]` I get errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142228/discussion-between-sumeet-sharma-and-ps0604).